# Transform any graph to bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any method which can transform any graph to bipartite graph? For example, if I were given a graph, in order to make it to become bipartite, I can delete vertices which lie in the two vertices sets so that I obtain two sets of vertices with no edge within the set.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "transform"?

Comment: Means convert. We con do anything on the graph as long as we can make it become a bipartite graph

Comment: That's equally vague. Deleting all of the edges will give you a bipartite graph. So would deleting all but two vertices. Or deleting the graph entirely and replacing it with $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: Those are silly examples, but the point I mean to make is that if you want more interesting answers, you need to be more precise about what kind of answer you're looking for. Is there a particular reason that you want to be able to produce a bipartite graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A natural way to turn a graph into a bipartite graph is to [subdivide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29) each edge, i.e., replace each edge by a path of length $2$.